# jQuery get value and set in id

Tags: jquery

I want a slider who changes dynamically the txt id="xd"

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider1" id="myRange1">

<div id="xd">86</div>
```

script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
/* Hier der jQuery-Code */

$('#myRange1').oninput(function() {
  var xy = $('#myRange1').val();
  $('#xd').innerHTML("xy");
})
}); </script>
```

Comment: `innerHTML(xy)` (no quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `html()` instead of `innerHTML` and `.on('change',` instead of `oninput`.

**NOTE:** You need to pass the variable not a string to the `html()` like :

```
$('#xd').html(xy);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myRange1').on('change', function() {
    var xy = $('#myRange1').val();
    $('#xd').html(xy);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider1" id="myRange1">

<div id="xd">86</div>
```

Comment: BTW, I didn't know that there is something like .on('change  because in all javascript tutorials for sliders and stuff like that stands oninput/other words that are used in javascript, but NOT in jQuery. How can I translate JS code to jQuery? I mean where can I look what JS code equals to which jQuery code? For example the JS code oninput equals to .on('change'

Comment: I'm new to web development, I don't know where I can look up quickly for things lke that

Comment: The `oninput` event in jQuery will be `.on('input'` I have used `change` event since we use the `input` when we track the user inputs (when the use hitting the keyboard buttons), that's not the case here the cursor of slider `change` instead...

Comment: Glad I could help @JuriJurka there no specific place for those things you have google them.